# is there any common keyword to call both webdriver and appiumdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

Below methods will return webdriver and appiumdriver,

```
public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return webDriver;
    }
```

Below method will return appiumDriver,

```
public AppiumDriver getAppiumDriver() {
        return appiumDriver;
    }
```

Is it possible to merge both function using any common return type,

for example,

```
 public <Common returntype> getDriver(String drivertype){
if(drivertype =='WebDriver')
return webDriver;
else
return appiumDriver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `appiumDriver` and `webDriver` both implement (or extend..?) the `RemoteWebDriver` interface, so you should be able to use the abstract class.

Try:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = getDriver(DRIVERTYPE)
```

...

```
public RemoteWebDriver getDriver(String driverType) {
        if (driverType.equals("WebDriver")) {
            return webDriver;
        } else {
            return appiumDriver;
        }
    }
```